# Only Two Radio Button Select

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I'm having a problem where only two of my radio buttons operate, but all three are made the same way.

Not sure if I'm missing something or what. The two execute wonderfully, the third, not so much.

Setting the other buttons to null was the suggestion of a colleague of mine, but still nothing. For simplicity's sake I've watered this down to changing the background of a window with colors. I'm not very familiar with this language so any help is appreciated.

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            RadioButton Green = new RadioButton();
            RadioButton Red = new RadioButton();
            RadioButton Blue = new RadioButton();
            Green.Content = "Green";
            Red.Content = "Red";
            Blue.Content = "Blue";
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Green);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Blue);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Red);
            Green.Margin = new Thickness(X, Y, 0, 0);
            Red.Margin = new Thickness(X, Y, 0, 0);
            Blue.Margin = new Thickness(X, Y, 0, 0);
            Green.Checked += delegate
            {
                Window.Background = Brushes.Green;
                Red = null;
                Blue = null;

            };
            Red.Checked += delegate
            {
                Window.Background = Brushes.Red;
                Green = null;
                Blue = null;
            };
            Blue.Checked += delegate
            {
                Window.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                Green = null;
                Red = null;
            };
    }
```

Comment: no repro. please create [mcve]. btw setting `Red = null; Green = null;` is useless, and can potentially become harmful, if those captured local variables are used in event handlers to get some property value

Answer (score 0):

Give your radio buttons a `GroupName`. Make sure they have the same `GroupName` and then they will be mutually exclusive within the group:

```
var button = new RadioButton();
button.GroupName = "SomeGroup";
```

Please see [this](https://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html) tutorial for more details.

Another note, I am not sure why you are making the other radio buttons `null` when one is clicked in the `Checked` handler.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I added group names and I still cannot select the third radio button. The suggestion to set the other buttons to null was a suggestion from another kid in my dorm.

Comment: @Christheyankee Why are you setting the button to null when you select one of them?

Comment: it was suggested by a friend in my dorm, wasn't originally gonna do that and it isn't in the real code. Just wanted to show I'd tried it

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out the Buttons were unconstrained so their hitboxes were overlapping. Simply adding the following definitions fixed it:

```
Red.Height = 15;
Red.Width = 60;
Red.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
Red.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```

Comment: this is a kind of answer which is impossible to guess if the question does not provide [mcve]